# Two way binding in directive broken

Tags: angularjs, directive

I think there's something I'm missing about two-way binding in my directives.

In the page's controller (`ScheduleEditCtrl`) there's an array of objects (`scheduleList`) (and some other properties).

This is used in the view thusly:

```
<undo-support watch-on="scheduleEdit.scheduleList"
    can-undo="scheduleEdit.canUndo"
    can-redo="scheduleEdit.canRedo"
    is-watch-on-initialized="scheduleEdit.isScheduleInitialized"></undo-support>
```

The directive:

```
angular.module('xnuapp')
    .directive('undoSupport', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            controller : 'UndoSupportCtrl',
            controllerAs : 'undoSupport',
            scope: {
                watchOn: '=watchOn',
                canUndo: '=canUndo',
                canRedo: '=canRedo',
                isWatchOnInitialized: '=isWatchOnInitialized'
            }
        };
    });
```

In the directive's controller (`UndoSupportCtrl`) it may be that an item in the array (`watchOn`) gets updated.

`$scope.watchOn = angular.copy(commands[--pointer]);`

My understanding is that when that `watchOn` gets updated, it should reflect back to the `scheduleEdit.scheduleList`, but through various logging triggers, I've found that the `scheduleList` property of the `ScheduleEditCtrl` never changes, even when `watchOn` does. Where should to see what prevents this from happening?